# Need help to loop a FindNext function

Tags: vba, loops, find

I am currently dealing with big data tables and need to made a reconciliation between two of them.
Here are what the tables look like:

```
1st table:
CODE1 DATE1 VALUE CODEEXIST
      DATE2 VALUE
      DATEx VALUE
CODE2 DATE1 VALUE CODEEXIST
      DATEy VALUE
      ...

2nd table:
DATE1 CODE1
DATE1 CODE2
DATE2 CODE3
DATE2 CODE1
...
```

In fact, for example, I need to collect in the 1st table the value for CODE1 at DATE1 and to paste it in the 2nd table on the right row by matching both code and date for each CODEx and DATEy. I put a mark "CODEEXIST" on fourth column to simplify the macro creation.

Actually, I was thinking to made nested loops such as below:

```
Sub reco()

For i = 1 To 100
    If Cells(i, 4) = "CODEEXIST" Then
        For y = 1 To 100
            If Sheets("Table2").Cells(y, 2).Value = Sheets("Table1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                For Z = i To Range("D:D").Find(What:="CODEEXIST", After:=Cells(i, 4))
                    If Sheets("Table2").Cells(y, 1).Value = Sheets("Table1").Cells(Z, 2).Value Then
                        Sheets("Table2").Cells(y, 3).Value = Sheets("Table1").Cells(Z, 3).Value
                    End If
                Next Z
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

But code does not work because of Find function.
I also wondered if there was an easier way to get that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the intent of the line  `For Z = i To Range("D:D").Find(What:="CODEEXIST", After:=Cells(i, 4))`. What do you hope for it to do? The find function returns a single-cell Range Object. Since you haven't specified a property and it isn't in a Set statement, the Range Object uses its default member `Range.Value`. So you are using the Value of the cell in the `For` Loop. But the Value is `"CODEEXIST"`, which cannot be used as the upper bound of a loop.

Comment: Maybe you want to add `.Row - 1`? So the loop would go from the current "CODEEXIST" to the next "CODEEXIST" (minus 1 row to not actually include the next "CODEEXIST"). But this strategy will fail on the bottom of the sheet. The last "CODEEXIST" will not have another one below it and will wrap around to the top of the sheet causing the For loop to exit without any action.

Comment: Hello, I finally replaced the For next loop with .Find function by a Do until Loop. Look at it: `Do Until Cells(Z, 5) = "isinexist"
                        If Sheets("BLOG2022").Cells(y, 3).Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(Z, 1).Value Then
                            Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value = "found"
                            Z = Z + 1
                        Else
                        Z = Z + 1
                        End If
                    Loop`

Comment: Have you considered using a formula instead of a macro?

Comment: I do not visualize how to do that without a macro.

Comment: @AlexCauwel I would try something like this `=XLOOKUP(Destination!Date&Destination!Code, Source!Date&Source!Code, Source!Value)`, where Source is a name of a sheet with 1st table, Destination - with 2nd table, Date and Code and Value -  corresponding named ranges with data (should be defined separately for each sheet).

Comment: Alright thank you, I will try it !